# Issues when installing camelot

Tags: python-3.6

Issue while importing camelot on anaconda

I installed camelot-py[cv] using pip (since conda forget was taking forever) and althogh it successfully installed, I am getting the following error when importing in a python file:

SystemError: initialization of _ARC4 failed without raising an exception

Can someone help me with this please? Appreciate your kind help.

Thanks
R